# Select Which Database Mail Profile is used in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am confused about Database mail profiles in SQL Server 2008 R2. When setting up severity notifications as well as "notify operator tasks" in maintenance plans, what determines what mail profile is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since "operators" are part of SQL Server Agent, I'm guessing it'll use whatever mail profile you've configured that to use.

To review/change it, right click SQL Server Agent in Management Studio, and choose Properties. Go to the "Alert System" page, and look for the "Mail profile" drop-down menu near the top. You may also have to check "Enable mail profile", and set "Mail system" to "Database Mail" if you haven't already.

Comment: Wonder if this sets the same thing as what I just posted....

Comment: @Kyle_Brandt db2's answer is the one that specifies which mail profile to use for the Agent operator emails.  The default option on the configuration screen that you showed allows users to execute sp_send_dbmail without specifying the profile_name parameter

Answer (score 0):

Think of an operator as a destination.  The database mail profile is the sender.

When you configure a database mail profile you are telling SQL what mail server to use, and what "sender" email address to use.

Operators are the people you want to notify via email.

Comment: But you can have multiple profiles I believe, so which profile gets used?

Comment: I have only ever set up one profile, and it gets used by default. Sorry.

Comment: You can have multiple profiles and you the "sending" email doesn't have to be a real email account (DoNotRespond@yourdomain.com) does appear to be the sender, a cosmetic thing that some managers like.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the default profile is what gets used, to set the default profile:

1. **Configure Database Mail:**
   [image]
2. **Configure Profile Security:**
   [image]
3. **Set the desired profile to default:**
   [image]